# Count of counts with null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm stuck on a problem that should be simple.
Suppose I have two tables: `authors` and `books`. For this example we will assume that a book has only one author.
I'd like to have a report that expresses the amount authors having written x books, e.g:

| number_of_books | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 |

...

The thing is that when I (outer) join the books and authors I get `NULL` values for the books.

My best approach was to do it in two queries, one with a `inner join` so I exclude the authors not having written a book yet and then I add the count of them programmatically.

Here's my query

```sql
select
  book_count,
  count(*)
from (
  select
    a.id,
    count(*) as book_count
  from authors a
  join books b
  on a.id = b.author_id
  group by a.id
) a
group by book_count
```

How can I do this in only one query ?

EDIT: here's a minimal example

```sql
create table authors (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(100)
);

create table books (
    id int primary key,
    title varchar(255),
    author_id int
);    
    
insert into authors values 
    (1, 'Isaac Asimov'),
    (2, 'Ray Bradbury'),
    (3, 'Aldous Huxley'),
    (4, 'Bruno Dusausoy');

insert into books values
    (1, 'Foundation', 1),
    (2, 'Foundation and Empire', 1),
    (3, 'Second Foundation', 1),
    (4, 'Fahrenheit 451', 2),
    (5, 'Brave New World', 3);
```

With the query mentioned above, I don't get the row `0, 1`

| book_count | count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

If I do a `left join` I get

| book_count | count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |

So `NULL` are not the same as `0`

Comment: The current query is fine. (Which dbms are you using?)

Comment: @jarlh Indeed, it's fine but it doesn't count the `NULL`s as zero books, so it's incomplete. I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: A [mcve] is always a great start when asking SQL questions. To avoid too much guessing.

Comment: @jarlh I've edited the question to include a minimal example. Hope it's clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about left joining the books to the authors.
Then the authors without books will have a 0 book_count.

> ```
> select
>   book_count,
>   count(*) as amount
> from (
>   select
>     author.id as author_id,
>     count(book.id) as book_count
>   from authors as author
>   left join books as book
>     on book.author_id = author.id
>   group by author.id
> ) a
> group by book_count
> order by book_count
> ```

| book_count | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c7b3a65dd6232ce6bd9535e2c58d528c)*

Comment: It then counts all the `NULL`s as one book, thus adding them to the amount of authors having written one book

Comment: no, count of nulls will be 0 normally.  So for book_count 0 the amount will represent the number of authors without books.

Comment: I've included a minimal example and put the results with inner and outer join.

Comment: See fiddle, seems correct. But note that I didn't use `count(*)` for book_count.

Comment: Ooooh, the `count(book.id)` instead of `count(*)` changes everything. Thanks a lot !